# Using multiple filter url params with QUnit

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, qunit

According to the QUnit documentation, you can specify a filter param in the url specifying which qunit module you want to run (?filter=[module]). Is there a way that you can specify multiple modules?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That was actually supported once, before moving to the filter=[module] syntax. Current QUnit doesn't support that anymore.

You could name your modules in a way that you can still filter them in grousp: "modx module 1", "modx module 2", then filter=modx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new "module=[module]" syntax.